# Android Studio - IllegalStateException While Using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, illegalstateexception

I'm using Retrofit library in Android studio for communicating with a web server in http requests.
On One of my requests I send a post request to the server.
In This Line:

```
Call<UploadRoomResponse> call = service.UploadRoom("Bearer " + token, new UploadRoomRequest(new Vector<String>() , angels, RoomName));
```

This is thrown:

```
 throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute method for android:onClick", e);
```

This is my IService interface:

```
public interface IService
{

    @POST("api/users/login")
    Call<LoginResponse> Login(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);


    @POST("api/users/signup")
    Call<SignupResponse> Signup(@Body SignupRequest signupRequest);


    @GET("api/users/rooms")
    Call<GetRoomsResponse> GetRooms(@Header("Authorization") String token);

    @POST("api/rooms")
    Call<UploadRoomResponse> UploadRoom(@Header("Authorization") String token, UploadRoomRequest uploadRoomRequest);
}
```

This is my response and request classes:

```
public class UploadRoomResponse extends BaseResponse
{
    private int roomId;

    public UploadRoomResponse(String message, int roomId)
    {
        super(message);
        this.roomId = roomId;
    }

    public int GetRoomId()
    {
        return roomId;
    }



}
```

```
public class UploadRoomRequest
{
    private List<String> files;
    private List<Float> angles;
    private String roomName;

    public UploadRoomRequest(List<String> files, List<Float> angles, String roomName)
    {
        this.files = files;
        this.angles = angles;
        this.roomName = roomName;
    }

    public List<String> GetFiles()
    {
        return files;
    }

    public List<Float> GetAngles()
    {
        return angles;
    }

    public String GetRoomName()
    {
        return roomName;
    }
}
```

Presenter function:

```
private void communicateUploadRoom(String token, String url)
    {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        IService service = retrofit.create(IService.class);
        List<Float> angels = new Vector<Float>();

        //adding all the angles of the images to the request
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            angels.add(90 - Images.get(i).GetPitch());
        }
        angels.add(Math.abs(Images.get(2).GetPitch()));


        Call<UploadRoomResponse> call = service.UploadRoom("Bearer " + token, new UploadRoomRequest(new Vector<String>() , angels, RoomName));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadRoomResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UploadRoomResponse> call, Response<UploadRoomResponse> response)
            {
                UploadRoomResponse uploadRoomResponse = response.body();
                if(uploadRoomResponse != null && uploadRoomResponse.GetMessage() == null)
                {
                    ClearSteps();
                    View.ToastUpload("Room Uploaded");
                }
                else
                {
                    View.ToastUpload(uploadRoomResponse.GetMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UploadRoomResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: c.www.roomodel, PID: 1299
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6614)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6591)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:786)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25948)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6614) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6591) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:786) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25948) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)
        for method IService.UploadRoom
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:720)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:711)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:729)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameter(ServiceMethod.java:348)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:202)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy0.UploadRoom(Unknown Source)
        at c.www.roomodel.app.Activities.UploadRoom.UploadRoomPresenter.communicateUploadRoom(UploadRoomPresenter.java:170)
```

Activity Code:

```
package c.www.roomodel.app.Activities.UploadRoom;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
import c.www.roomodel.R;
import c.www.roomodel.app.Activities.Camera.CameraActivity;
import c.www.roomodel.app.Activities.Info.InfoActivity;
import c.www.roomodel.app.Activities.Options.OptionsActivity;
import c.www.roomodel.app.Models.GlobalUser;
import c.www.roomodel.app.Models.Image;
import c.www.roomodel.app.Models.UploadStep;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.LayoutDirection;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

public class UploadRoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UploadRoomView{

    public LinearLayout mainLayout;
    public UploadRoomPresenter Presenter;

    public Button uploadButton;
    public Button clearButton;
    public EditText RoomName;
    //list of V icons of steps
    public List<ImageView> Vs;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_room);




        RoomName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.RoomName);

        addNameListener();

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upload_button);
        clearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear_button);


        Vs = new Vector<ImageView>();


        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }


        mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        Presenter = new UploadRoomPresenter(this);
        ChangeRoomName(Presenter.GetRoomName());

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(b != null)
        {
            Presenter.SetImage(b.getInt("id"), new Image(b.getByteArray("data"), b.getFloat("pitch")));
        }
        Presenter.CheckAvailableImages();

    }

    //This function creates a button dynamically of a step
    //it gets parameters:
    //right - is the step positioned right
    //background - background image of button
    //(This function doesn't define a button click event)
    private Button CreateStepButton(Boolean right, int background)
    {
        Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.info_camera_height), getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.info_camera_height));


        button.setBackgroundResource(background);

        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

        //if linear layout is positioned right
        if(right)
        {
            params.leftMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.step_button_margin);
        }
        else
        {
            params.rightMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.step_button_margin);
        }


        button.setLayoutParams(params);

        return button;
    }

    //This function creates a linear layout dynamically of a step
    //it gets parameters:
    //right - is the step positioned right
    private LinearLayout CreateLinearLayout(Boolean right)
    {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.step_width), getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.step_height));

        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.step_layout);


        if(right)
        {
            params.rightMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.step_margin);
            params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            linearLayout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
        }
        else
        {
            params.leftMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.step_margin);
            params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            linearLayout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        }

        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        params.topMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.step_top_margin);


        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

        return linearLayout;
    }


    private TextView CreateText(Boolean right, String text)
    {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-black", Typeface.NORMAL));
        textView.setText(text);

        textView.setLayoutParams(params);



        return textView;
    }

    private ImageView CreateVIcon(boolean right)
    {
        ImageView v = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.info_camera_height), getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.info_camera_height));


        v.setImageResource(R.drawable.v);

        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;

        //if linear layout is positioned right
        if(right)
        {
            params.leftMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.step_button_margin);
        }
        else
        {
            params.rightMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.step_button_margin);
        }


        v.setLayoutParams(params);

        return v;
    }


    public void CreateStep(Boolean right, UploadStep step, int id)
    {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = CreateLinearLayout(right);
        linearLayout.setId(id);
        ImageView v = CreateVIcon(right);
        v.setAlpha(0);
        Vs.add(v);
        Button cameraButton = CreateStepButton(right, R.drawable.camera_button);
        Button infoButton = CreateStepButton(right, R.drawable.info_button);
        TextView textView = CreateText(right, step.GetTitle());

        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(UploadRoomActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("id", ((View)v.getParent()).getId());
                takePictureIntent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(takePictureIntent);
                finish();
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, ((View)v.getParent()).getId());
                }
            }
        });

        infoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Presenter.ChangeRoomName(RoomName.getText().toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(UploadRoomActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                UploadStep step = Presenter.GetStep(((View)v.getParent()).getId());
                b.putInt("image", step.GetImage());
                b.putInt("info", step.GetInfo());
                b.putString("title", step.GetTitle());


                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        linearLayout.addView(v);
        linearLayout.addView(cameraButton);
        linearLayout.addView(infoButton);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);


        mainLayout.addView(linearLayout);
    }






    @Override
    public void CheckStep(int id)
    {
        Vs.get(id).setAlpha(255);
    }

    public void changeToOptions(View view)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(UploadRoomActivity.this, OptionsActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void enableButton(boolean enable)
    {
        uploadButton.setEnabled(enable);
        if(enable)
        {
            uploadButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.enabledButton));
        }
        else
        {
            uploadButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.disabledButton));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void InvisibleV()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Vs.size(); i++)
        {
            Vs.get(i).setAlpha(0);
        }
    }

    //This function is an 'on click' function for the clear button
    //clears all images and V's
    //clears all images and V's
    public void ClearClick(View v)
    {
        Presenter.ClearSteps();
    }


    //This function is an 'on click' function for the upload button
    //Uploads the images
    public void UploadClick(View v)
    {
        Presenter.TryUploadRoom(GlobalUser.User.GetToken(), getResources().getString(R.string.baseUrl));
    }



    @Override
    public void ClearRoomName()
    {
        RoomName.setText("");
    }


    private void addNameListener()
    {
        RoomName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                Presenter.ChangeRoomName(RoomName.getText().toString());
                Presenter.canEnableUpload(RoomName.getText().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        });
    }



    @Override
    public void ChangeRoomName(String name)
    {
        RoomName.setText(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void ToastUpload(String s)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



}
```

What could be the cause of the exception which is thrown?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like your error is in the XML file & the Activity. Post those.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace and the part of the code it originates from? It will help us see where in the code the exception is being thrown from

Comment: Those were added now.

Comment: add you complete activity and xml code, its not the retrofit thats causing issue.

Comment: xaml is a bit empty because views are added in the code.

Comment: The activity code is added.

Comment: did you check the other button, is it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the root error:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)
>     for method IService.UploadRoom
> ```

This is the referenced method:

> ```
> @POST("api/rooms")
> Call<UploadRoomResponse> UploadRoom(@Header("Authorization") String token, UploadRoomRequest uploadRoomRequest);
> ```

Perhaps you've forgotten `@Body` for the `UploadRoomRequest` param?